# Auto-share link when enter site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to automatically share a link to facebook when a user enters a certain site?

1. Users enters site.
2. User accepts to use app that my customer creates.
3. When the user enters an article on the site, the article url is automatically shared to facebook.

Possible or not?